# Текст с градиентом и тенью

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть такая штука градиент тексту, и тень. Легко нагуглить и применить. Только вот применить 2 этих решения сразу - лично для меня оказалось проблемой. Есть так же другой глюк, скажем решение..

```
<div style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #000);-webkit-background-clip: text;-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;">
Текст
</div>
```

..на ура работает в хроме, вот в файерфокс'е - нет (остальное - не важно)

Использовал ли кто такую конструкцию? Может ли кто поделиться?

p.s. самому изначально хотелось найти решение, в котором градиент поверх цвета (ну там для IE всяких)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, такое реализуемо на данный момент только в Chrome и Safari.

Если допустимо использование javascript, то вот решение:

**[Попиксельные градиенты для текста [Плагин для jQuery]](http://mrnix.ru/pxgradient/)**
(IE6++, Firefox3++, Opera9.64++, Chrome1++, Safari4++)

Или еще вариант: используйте в качестве фона предварительно подготовленные картинки с текстом, поверх которых располагайте прозрачный текст, чтобы его можно было скопировать.

**[Посмотреть пример реализации второго варианта](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/NtNe7/embedded/result/)**.

Comment: вообщем по разному пробовал, но на ВСЕ решения так тень и не смог наложить. т.е. либо тень, либо градиент. Может я как то не так пробую, но пока дела никак (

Comment: господа, 2 пальца вверх.. у вас получилось совместить 2 решения? вопрос был не в чистом градиенте, а градиент + тень.

Comment: Добавил пример реализации второго варианта.  
Проверил работоспособность в IE 7+ и последних версиях Chrome, Firefox и Opera.

Comment: Ответ - шаг вперед! Но пока конкретно тень + градиент 'спарить' не удалось

Answer (score 1):

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg,#ffe188,#ffae00);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #ffae00;
filter: drop-shadow(0 4px 0 #c90c00) drop-shadow(0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]